# Matrices and ranks

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is matrix if order $4\times 8$ and $B$ is a matrix of order $8\times 4$ s.t. $AB=I$  then find the ranks of $A$ and $B$.

I know rank of $AB$ is $4$ but I can't find rank of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ has only 4 rows its rank is at most 4.

The rank of $AB=I$ is precisely 4. We know that $$\text {Rank} (AB)\le \text {Rank}(A)$$ 
and therefore the rank of $A$ is at least 4.

Thus the rank of $A$ is 4 and the equivalent argument proves that the rank of $B$ is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Rank of A = rank of B = 4.
Because, we know that, 
Rank of(AB) <= min{rank of A, rank of B}. And that ensure that rank of A and rank of B can not lass then 4.
Now, we also know that row rank and colome rank of a matrix are same. In matrix A row space is the subspace of R^8. And colome space is the subspace of R^4. Then it's clear that colome rank is less than 4. 
So those two statements ensure that rank of A is 4.
Similar case happen in the matrix B.

Comment: In general we can only say that the rank of AB is less than or equal to the minimum of the two ranks.